# Open a new activity by pressing a button using on'Click

Tags: java, android-activity, onclick

I am trying to open a activity "one" from the MainActivity when the button "button1" (onClick:one) is pressed.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a method with name `one` that takes a `View` and then create an `Intent`. Something like this:

```
public void one(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, one.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: When I did this method and tried it on the emulator the "activity_activity1.xml" did not open. Why? Shoud I add something?